# Can the git tree hash be used to uniquely identify a specific state in a subdirectory

Tags: git, hash

I would like to use the hashes used in the git tree object to uniquely identify the state of a subdirectory under git, specifically as an index to an artifact repo for build avoidance. Something like this:

```
# Get hash for source tree in <path-do-dir>/<dir-name>
git cat-file -p HEAD^{tree}:<path-to-dir> | awk '$4 == "<dir-name>" { print $3 }'
```

My question is whether those hashes are truly persistent. Naive experimentation suggests that it works, but I wonder if anyone is doing this for real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^{tree}` here is not actually doing you any good.

There's an even simpler method:

```
git rev-parse HEAD:<path-to-dir>/<dir-name>
```

e.g.:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD:t | awk '$4 == "t9604" { print $3 }'
846893f0b08b1fa03a6383c9a4deade32c16e929
$ git rev-parse HEAD:t/t9604
846893f0b08b1fa03a6383c9a4deade32c16e929
```

The SHA-1 of a tree object is a checksum of the "contents" of the tree, which is to say, its tree-ness, plus a list of all the names in the tree along with their mode and type and SHA-1's.  So, yes: it identifies the state of the directory.  It might identify it *too* strongly, as it will change if any of the blobs contained in the tree even changes modes (`+x` or `-x`).

If you want to make sure that `HEAD:path` names a tree (not a blob) you can use `git cat-file -t` on the result of the `rev-parse` (but that's probably not needed here).

Comment: That's great, exactly what I need. This, combined with the hashes of all the dependencies will work nicely for build avoidance. I <3 git.

Comment: What's `t/t9604`?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: a directory in the Git repository for Git. It contains test files (input files, actually) for `git cvsimport`. Hence, just a convenient example to show `git rev-parse` extracting hash IDs of trees.

Comment: @torek So I could replace it with `src/bar/SomeDirectory`?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: assuming you have such a path in your Git repository, yes. `git rev-parse` finds the hash ID of any existing object given a valid name for that object. `<rev>:<path>` is such a name.

Comment: Adding, root folder is empty after `<rev>:`. Without `:` you get the commit-id.